# fullPage.js menu disappearing

Tags: css, fullpage.js

I have a problem with [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage). My menu doesn't stay in place at the top of the site, but rather disappears when I scroll down. Still, there is an offset for the slides, but the menu isn't there. Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#firstPage">firstPage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#secondPage">secondPage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#thirdPage">thirdPage</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fullpage">
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
      <div class="section">Some section</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The initialization:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        scrollingSpeed: 300,
        menu: '#menu',
        anchors:['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage']
    });
});
```

In the CSS, I have removed anything that might cause troubles, but here is it:

```
.section{
    background-color: olive;
    z-index: -1;
}
.section:nth-child(2n){
    background-color: orange;
}
```

This screenshot shows that the navigation is displayed properly at the start. When you scroll down, it disappears, but there is still a gap at the top where the navigation normally would be. I tried manually setting position:fixed to the nav, that way it didn't disappear, but the links werent clickable.
[image]

The problem: the sections are placed above the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a fixed positioned menu for that. Something like this:

```
#menu{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
```

You can clearly see this in the [fullpage.js online examples](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

Answer (score 0):

only add this code to style or css file:

```
#menu {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 50;
        background: red;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

        #menu li {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 15px;
        }

            #menu li a {
                color: #fff;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```

sample code snippet:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            scrollingSpeed: 300,
            menu: '#menu',
            anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage']
        });
    });
```

```css
  .section {
            background-color: olive;
            z-index: -1;
        }

            .section:nth-child(2n) {
                background-color: orange;
            }

        #menu {
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 50;
            background: red;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

            #menu li {
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 15px;
            }

                #menu li a {
                    color: white;
                    text-decoration: none;
                }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.7/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#firstPage">firstPage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#secondPage">secondPage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#thirdPage">thirdPage</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="fullpage">
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
        <div class="section">Some section</div>
    </div>
```